# A function that checks for duplicate elements in an array

Tags: javascript

Is there a simpler way to implement this function?

```
function has_duplicates(arr) {
  var myObject = {};

  for (var key in arr) {
    if (myObject[arr[key]])
      return true;
    else
      myObject[arr[key]] = true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(has_duplicates(["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux", "foo"]));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function has_duplicates(arr) {
```

In JS, function names are usually in camelCase. So this should be `hasDuplicates`.

```
for (var key in arr) {
```

Don't use `for-in` with arrays. `for-in` loops will run through properties, including prototype properties. Use a regular `for` loop with counters. A `forEach` would also work, but you can't bail out in the middle of the array.

So far, iirc, a loop and hash is favorable in this scenario since it's just `O(n)` and you can bail out in the middle of the operation.

---

Another way to do it is the following. The concept is that when a value appears twice, `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` will not be the same, thus adding the entry to the array created by `filter`.

```
function hasDuplicates(arr){
  return !!arr.filter(fuction(value){
    return arr.indexOf(value) !== arr.lastIndexOf(value);
  }).length;
}
```

Another way to do it is by using ES6's `Set`. The concept is that sets only hold unique values. When you try to add a duplicate, it won't be added to the set. If there is a mismatch in the array length and set size, you jumped over a duplicate somewhere, thus revealing the existence of the duplicate.

```
function hasDuplicates(arr){
  var set = new Set();
  arr.forEach(function(value){ set.add(value); });
  return set.size !== arr.length;
}
```

Going with @PeterCordes's suggestion, you can use `Set` and check on each iteration the size mismatch. We can assume `false` until a mismatch happens.

```
function hasDuplicates(arr){
  var set = new Set();
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    set.add(arr[i]);
    if(set.size !== i + 1) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, use a hash-based Set to get an O(n) duplicate check.  Checking indexOf == lastIndexOf is not great: if there are repeats between element 5 and element 10, for example, you're still scanning the entire array for elements 0 to 4.  You're repeating even more work than is needed with an O(n^2) time solution that doesn't use any temporary storage.   A very similar question came up on SO, where I went into detail about different ways to use indexOf: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32523601/224132.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah. Hash is better. But if performance isn't a concern, readability and maintainability is always the next in line. Who wouldn't want a 3-liner duplicate detection? :D

Comment: I *was* talking about the 3-line implementation using ES6's `Set`, which the docs say must use a hash table under the hood, or something else that is at least sub-linear time per insert / lookup (so a binary tree of some sort is allowed, but not linear searches).  https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-set-objects.  Also, if you expect to find a duplicate early in a long list, check `set.size` after every add.  (This is probably faster than checking membership and then adding, which probably hashes the input twice.)

Comment: That last code example you added does not work.  `set.size` increases as the loop continues, but `arr.length` remains the same throughout the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `for..in` to iterate an array, because `for..in` is for *enumerating* objects and will enumerate over properties, including prototype properties. To iterate, use a normal `for` loop with a counter.

### ES5

ES5 introduced some array iteration methods.  [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is the logical choice for this case, since it terminates the loop as soon as you've found an element that matches your condition.

```js
function hasDuplicates(arr) {
  var valueHash = {};
  return arr.some(function(item) {
    var exists = valueHash[item];
    valueHash[item] = true;
    return exists;
  });
}

document.write(hasDuplicates(["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux", "foo"]));
```

### ES6

If you can use ES6, you have the new `Set` object available, which is optimized for this kind of work.  The constructor takes an iterable (such as an array) as an argument.  So, you can just create a `Set`, and compare it's `size` to the array's `length`:

```js
function hasDuplicates(arr) {
  return new Set(arr).size < arr.length;
}

document.write(hasDuplicates(["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux", "foo"]));
```

Now, I don't know, but it's conceivable that this could be slow on a large array.  If your array is large, and there could be many duplicates, it might be faster to loop through and add items to the `Set` one at a time.  Use the JS5 function from above, but use a `Set` instead of an `Object`:

```js
function hasDuplicates(arr){
  var set = new Set();
  return arr.some(function(item) {
    var exists = set.has(item);
    set.add(item);
    return exists;
  });
}

document.write(hasDuplicates(["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux", "foo"]));
```

It has been suggested that checking `Set.has()` followed by `Set.add()` could require the hash being computed twice, and thus be slower.  If that's the case, it may perform better by checking `Set.size` instead of using `Set.has()`.

```js
function hasDuplicates(arr){
  var set = new Set();
  return arr.some(function(item, i) {
    return set.add(item).size == i; // while the array is distinct, set.size is i + 1
  });
}

document.write(hasDuplicates(["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux", "foo"]));
```